# Deconstructing enums in Rust

Tags: rust, netcdf

Very new to rust and trying to understand how to idiomatically work with this enum: https://docs.rs/netcdf/latest/netcdf/attribute/enum.AttrValue.html

How do I write a function that, given the `netcdf::attribute::AttrValue` enum and variant I expect I'm in, returns to me the primitive that the enum variant was constructed from? Something about deconstruction and generic functions, but I can't get a nice solution off the ground. Here's my best attempt:

```
use netcdf;
use std::env;

fn main() -> Result<(), netcdf::error::Error> {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let file = netcdf::open(&args[1])?; // data/CCMP_Wind_Analysis_19930103_V03.0_L4.0.nc
  
    let vwnd = &file.variable("vwnd").expect("Could not find variable 'vwnd'");
  
    // help me re-write this hacky block in a nice function that works for any variant:

    let mut units: String = String::from("null");
    let x = vwnd.attribute("units").unwrap().value().unwrap(); // here's the AttrValue enum
    if let netcdf::attribute::AttrValue::Str(v) = x {
        units = v;
    }
    println!("{}",units);

    // hack block complete    

    return Ok(())

}
```

This works - `units` does in fact have a `String`-type string in it - but this seems very not idiomatic. How should I turn this into an idiomatic rust function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would normally use the [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) trait for this. If the library author had provided `TryFrom` instances for his type, then you could simply write `String::try_from(v)` and get either an `Ok(string)` or an appropriate error.

Unfortunately, they didn't do so. You can always do it yourself with [the newtype pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-for-type-safety-and-abstraction), but it'll be a decent bit of legwork to get all of those types up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Silvio - for those looking for an explicit answer, here's how I interpreted Silvio's advice:

```
use netcdf;
use std::env;
use std::convert::TryFrom;

struct Wrapper{
    s: String
}

impl std::convert::TryFrom<netcdf::attribute::AttrValue> for Wrapper {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from(value: netcdf::attribute::AttrValue) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {

        if let netcdf::attribute::AttrValue::Str(v) = value {
            Ok(Wrapper{s: String::from(v)} )
        } else {
            Err("nope")
        }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), netcdf::error::Error> {
   let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

   let file = netcdf::open(&args[1])?; // data/CCMP_Wind_Analysis_19930103_V03.0_L4.0.nc
   let vwnd = &file.variable("vwnd").expect("Could not find variable 'vwnd'");

   let units = Wrapper::try_from(vwnd.attribute("units").unwrap().value().unwrap()).unwrap().s;
   println!("{:#?}", units);

   return Ok(())

}
```

I'm a little surprised so much work would be needed to extract a simple attribute, but that's a different question entirely.